# NHibernate Deleted object would be re-saved by cascade

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In my solution I have a branch of business objects with associations. So when I try save a root object after processing I get an exception with message "Deleted object would be re-saved by cascade". What means that after deleting of an object its still exists in collections, other association and so on. Does somebody knows how to get a list of references to the deleted object. 
Its very difficult to find references without debugger support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most common scenario *(my experience)* is having two root objects having collections of some pairing/middle object.

```
public class Employee 
{
    public virtual IList<Occupation> Occupations { get; set; }
}
public class Company
{
    public virtual IList<Occupation> Occupations { get; set; }
}
```

Now, we have the `Occupation` like this

```
public class Occupation
{
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual Company  Company  { get; set; }
}
```

So, what could happen:

1. we remove an **Occupation** from `employee.Occupations` collection.
2. During that transaction, unit of work, we also tuch and therefore load the **`Company`**
3. Company gets initiated. Its collection of Occupations get loaded. So the reference to removed **Occupation** is kept there
4. NHibernate says: `Deleted object would be re-saved by cascade`

Solution(s):

- be sure that the Company is never loaded (stays as proxy)
- or `Remove()` the Occupation also from `company.Occupations`
- do not use mapping like this on Company side:

*(do **not** use the cascade)*

```
<bag name="Occupations" lazy="true" inverse="true" batch-size="25" 
     cascade="all-delete-orphan">
     // this above setting on Company side is making issues...
  <key column="Company_ID" />
  <one-to-many class="Occupation" />
</bag>
```

Comment: Yes, but what if I have a lot of object types and a lot of logic. And now I can't find which busness object holds the reference(Employee? or Company? or Ocupation? in my case its additionaly Address, Country etc) Because NHibernate exception doesn't contains usefull information. Is there any way to find out the source under debuger?

Comment: @Gattaka The root of your problem is you are mixing Persistence Model and Domain Model. Doing so impose NHibernate problems upon your business objects, such as this problem. You cannot freely change your persistence models (i.e. NHibernate mapped models) because the system passes it everywhere. Radim answer is correct, but this problem is quite difficult to debug, as it often only arises with certain data pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions didn't work for me. The instance I tried to delete was nowhere referenced in my code.

However, it was in NHhibernate. After clearing the session, it worked for me.