# NHibernate: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade. Replace object and remove old one

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to replace at TimeBlock object on a ProgramItem and then delete the old TimeBlock object. It's the delete part that gives me problems.
I have some 'relative' simple nHibernate problems deleting the old TimeBlock object.

**Exception:**
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)[*.Model.TimeBlock#15]
*15 is the Id of the oldTimeBlock*

I usually don't have any problems solving this kind of issue by I just tried almost any usages of:

```
oldTimeBlock.ProgramItems = new List<ProgramItem>();
programItem.TimeBlock = null;
```

and the save and delete blocks in any order and changing the mapping with Inverse().
**I need some fresh eyes - how could I make this work?**

Code:

```
public class TimeBlock
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ProgramItem> ProgramItems { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class TimeBlockMap : ClassMap<TimeBlock>
{
    public TimeBlockMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.ProgramItems).Cascade.SaveUpdate(); // Have tested with Inverse() but seemed to make no difference
    }
}


public class ProgramItem : ImageModel, IIdentifiable
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TimeBlock TimeBlock { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ProgramItemMap : ClassMap<ProgramItem>
{
    public ProgramItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.TimeBlock);
    }
}


//Delete old TimeBlock and set new TimeBlock to ProgramItem

var oldTimeBlock = programItem.TimeBlock;

using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    oldTimeBlock.ProgramItems = new List<ProgramItem>();
    programItem.TimeBlock = null;
    //session.Save(programItem);
    //session.Save(oldTimeBlock);
    session.Delete(oldTimeBlock);
    tx.Commit(); // location of the exception. If i move the delete oldTimeBlock part below the save programItem part it will still fail in the delete oldTimeBlock part.
}

using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    programItem.TimeBlock = timeBlock;
    session.Save(programItem);
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried explain what is happening in detail here

- [NHibernate Deleted object would be re-saved by cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27640560/1679310)
- [Delete an item from many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27610741/1679310)

I would say, that the point is here: the `ProgramItem` is referenced by some other collection. And that collection was also loaded into the session.

The best place where to start is - wherever is ProgramItem used (collection item, reference) change the mapping to `Cascade.None()`. Then try to execute your deletion code. That will work... surely, becuase now cascading in place... no way how to trigger that exception.

Next - start cascading by pieces. Be sure you know what is allowed, and then you will know which reference, collection is re-saving your object.

My own experience/approach is - if you delete the item from one place, explicitly delete it from others as well, if there is cascade. It could be challenging, but...

Comment: Thanks for the method to identify which Cascade caused the probelm. As you said it was another refernece collection - one that I missed - stupid..